# Cómo unir filas con un campo en común?

Tags: sql

Tengo la siguiente tabla. Como puedo unir las filas iguales en una sola, sumando sus cantidades también.

**Tabla1**

```
| NOMBRE | ENERO | FEBRERO|
| ------ | ----- | ------ |
| IVON   |  10   |   15   |
| XIMENA |   5   |   20   |
| JOSE   |  20   |   3    |
| IVON   |  4    |   2    |
```

**RESULTADO ESPERADO**

```
| NOMBRE | ENERO | FEBRERO |
| ------ | ----- | ------  |
|  IVON  |  14   |   17    |
| XIMENA |  5    |   20    |
|  JOSE  |  20   |   3     |
```

Comment: usando la sentencia Group By.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando `SUM()` y `GROUP BY`.

```sql
select nombre, sum(enero), sum(febrero)
from Tabla1
group by nombre
```